# duplication of rows without primary key

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

How to duplicate a row 40 times in PostgreSQL which **doesn't have a primary key attached to it**?

Ex:

```
14/11/2021
15/11/2021
```

Output should be:

```
14/11/2021
14/11/2021
14/11/2021
14/11/2021
..... 40 times
15/11/2021
15/11/2021
15/11/2021
15/11/2021
15/11/2021 
... 40 times
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? "[How to select a single row multiple times in PostgreSql](//stackoverflow.com/q/43203051/90527)", "[Duplicate (repeat) rows in sql query result](//stackoverflow.com/q/35293084/90527)", "[SQL: Repeat a result row multiple times, and number the rows](//stackoverflow.com/q/10423767/90527)", …

Answer (score 3):

We can try doing a cross join with the help of `generate_series`:

```sql
SELECT t1.date
FROM yourTable t1
CROSS JOIN generate_series(1, 40)
ORDER BY t1.date;
```